# How to put an XML document into another with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

I want to include an xml document with arbitrary user provided data in another one using nokogiri.
I have tried `Node#add_child` and encountered a problem: nokogiri looses namespace definition if there is a uri in `child_doc` that is also present in main `doc` but with a different prefix.

Example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML %(
  <s:rack xmlns:s="urn://shelf">
    <s:shelf></s:shelf>
  </s:rack>
)

child_doc = Nokogiri::XML %(
  <m:shelf xmlns:m="urn://shelf">
    <m:book></m:book>
  </m:shelf>
)

doc.root.add_child(child_doc.root)
doc.to_xml
# =>
# <s:rack xmlns:s="urn://shelf">
#   <s:shelf/>
#   <!-- namespace for prefix m is not declared! -->
#   <m:shelf>
#     <m:book/>
#   </m:shelf>
# </s:rack>
```

Namespace for prefix `m` is lost.

Here is the resulting doc object, pretty printed:

```
#(Document:0x1b2ce28 {
  name = "document",
  children = [
    #(Element:0x1b327c4 {
      name = "rack",
      namespace = #(Namespace:0x1b320a8 { prefix = "s", href = "urn://shelf" }),
      children = [
        #(Text "\n    "),
        #(Element:0x1b45f90 { name = "shelf", namespace = #(Namespace:0x1b320a8 { prefix = "s", href = "urn://shelf" }) }),
        #(Text "\n  "),
        #(Element:0x1a9e5d8 {
          name = "shelf",
          namespace = #(Namespace:0x1a87450 { prefix = "m", href = "urn://shelf" }),
          children = [
            #(Text "\n    "),
            #(Element:0x1a41dec { name = "book", namespace = #(Namespace:0x1a87450 { prefix = "m", href = "urn://shelf" }) }),
            #(Text "\n  ")]
          })]
      })]
  })
```

As you can see internally namespaces in added nodes are correct but they are serialized wrong. How do I get nokogiri to save them in the resulting xml?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimal code you've written toward solving the problem that demonstrates it, along with the minimum input and expected output. The two little lines of code don't help us as we can't duplicate anything you're seeing from it.

Comment: How do you want to reconcile different namespaces? Convert them all to one specific one? Use nesting namespaces? Namespaces are not necessary if your data tags don't collide, or if the tag collisions are not important to your goals.

Comment: @theTinMan Changed the question, hopefully it''s better now. I have to use namespaces because the child document is an arbitrary user provided xml and must not collide with the main doc. (it contains routing information)

Comment: That information needs to be in the question itself. Ambiguity in a question leads to broad answers, which don't help you or anyone else looking for the same solution in the future.